# Insert into `table` where not exist

Tags: java, mysql

I want to insert values into a table but need to check if the value exist in the last row or not.  I normally insert values like

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`column1`,`column2`,`column3`,`column4`) VALUES ('value1','value2','value3','value4')
```

But now I need to put a check, if the value1 exist in the last row of the table do not insert, insert otherwise.

For that I am trying to use

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS
```

I actually want to check the last row of the table if the value exist then it should not duplicate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can state explicitly what happens when the primary key for a table already exists. Example:

```
INSERT INTO table (...) VALUES (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!!! I actually want to check the last row of the table if the value exist then it should not duplicate it.

Comment: this is definitely the right answer that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Alias the sub select. It is mandatory in MySQL.

Comment: INSERT INTO tableName(column1, column2, column3, column4) SELECT value1,value2,value3,value4 FROM tableName 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableName m2 
WHERE m2.column1 = value1 AND m2.column2 = value2); Are you talking about something like this???

Answer (score 0):

as an aside, as per the documentation, in the WHERE NOT EXISTS select, you don't need to specify fields (value1, value2, in your case) because that is entirely ignored. So just use *

In any event, I believe this will answer your question:
[How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Adding an unique constraint on the pair (column 1, column 2) isn't a better way to do that ?

Comment: except for when the attempted insert will cause an error that your code isn't prepared to handle... otherwise, yeah, I'd say that's the best approach.